# Run command on hosts and sum of stdout at the end

Tags: ansible

I want to run a command on y hostgroups which gives '1' in stdout. After running in all hosts, I want sum of all 1.

For example, it runs on 5 hosts, for all 5 hosts I'll get 1 ... at the end I want 5 as output

Or may be a way to execute the command and calculate the sum in one task only.

```
- name: Check file in tmp
  shell: ls -ltrh /tmp/a.txt | wc -l
  register: count
  when: "'webserver' in group_names"
```

Answer (score 0):

An option would be to create a temporary file and use it for the shared purpose. The play below

```
- hosts: test_jails
  gather_facts: true
  tasks:
    - name: Create tempfile
      tempfile:
        state: file
      register: fcounter
      run_once: true
      delegate_to: localhost
    - name: Write hostname to the tempfile
      shell: "echo {{ ansible_hostname }} >> {{ fcounter.path }}"
      delegate_to: localhost

      # < --------- HERE COMES THE PLAY --------- >

    - name: Print number of hosts
      shell: "cat {{ fcounter.path }} | wc -l"
      register: counter
      run_once: true
      delegate_to: localhost
    - debug:
        var: counter.stdout
      run_once: true
```

gives:

```
ok: [test_01] => {
"counter.stdout": "3"
}
PLAY RECAP ****************************************************************
test_01                    : ok=5    changed=3    unreachable=0    failed=0   
test_02                    : ok=2    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0   
test_03                    : ok=2    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

Answer (score 0):

If I get your exact need, you can get the result without using shell. Please note that using json_query in my example below requires `pip install jmespath`. If this is not possible, you can most probably achieve the same result using the `map` filter combining 'extract' and 'attribute='.

```
- name: Check file exists on server
  stat:
    path: /tmp/a.txt
  register: a_file
  when: whatever_condition

- name: Count number of matches
  debug:
    msg: >-
      {{ 
        hostvars
        | json_query('*[].a_file.stat.exists')
        | map('ternary', 1, 0)
        | sum
      }}
  delegate_to: localhost
  run_once: true
```